# Hotkey is reopening workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook `Book1` which sets a hotkey on opening:

```
Public Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnKey "^m", "abc"

End Sub
```

Here is the code for `abc()`:

```
Sub abc()

bkName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
runString = "'" & bkName & "'!xyz"
Application.Run runString

End Sub


Sub xyz()

MsgBox "this book: " & ThisWorkbook.Name & vbNewLine & "active: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name    

End Sub
```

I have a workbook `Book2` with identical code.  When I open `Book1`, then open `Book2`, then close `Book2`, and then press **Ctrl**+**m**, `Book2` opens and I get a message box with:

```
this book: Book1.xlsm
active: Book1.xlsm
```

So `Book1` is running `abc()`, but I guess the `.OnKey` from `Book2`'s `Workbook_Open()` is causing `Book2` to reopen, even though it's not actually calling `Book2`'s `abc()`.

How can I prevent `Book2` from being reopened?  Is there a way to delete its `.OnKey` but leave `Book1`'s intact?

Comment: yep, same here. There must be some workaround... :d

Comment: What if we put this in workbook_Activate instead, and we remove it when Workbook_Deactivate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm, I tried it and it workd correctly if you use the Activate and Deactivate events.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^m", "abc"
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^m"
End Sub
```

When Book2 closes or deactivates, it will remove its OnKey. But then Book1 will activate and set its own OnKey. It works as desired, it will no longer reopen the closed workbook.

I think you cannot remove OnKey from one WB and leave it intact for another, since the OnKey is related to the Application object, not to the WB. But the workaround with Activate/Deactivate seems to work properly.